# Why does not appear FloatingActionButton?

Tags: java, android

I changed my question to a more understandable one. But now there was another problem. Why does not appear FloatingActionButton

Why does not appear FloatingActionButton
Why does not appear FloatingActionButton

---

```
public class Home extends MyAppCompact 
{
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home); //This is problem
    }

}
```

//

```
public class MyAppCompact extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.
                LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton=new FloatingActionButton(this);
        layoutParams.gravity= Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.RIGHT;
        layoutParams.setMargins(16,16,16,16);

        floatingActionButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_mic_white_24dp);
        floatingActionButton.setClickable(true);

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Bitmap bitmap=getScreenShot();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                Intent intent = new Intent(MyAppCompact.this, FeedBack.class);
                intent.putExtra("bitmapData", byteArray);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1=new LinearLayout.
                LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        addContentView(floatingActionButton,layoutParams1);

        //
//            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
//        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
//        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
//        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
//        android:layout_margin="16dp"
//        android:id="@+id/btnFloating"
//        android:clickable="true"
//        android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_white_24dp" />
    }

    public Bitmap getScreenShot() {
        View rootView = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        View screenView = rootView.getRootView();
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenView.getDrawingCache());
        screenView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that one view closes another. And I need to put 1 on 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class extends `MyAppCompat` class. Where you create the `FloatingActionButton` and then use `addContentView` method to add the FAB. Your Home class extends this `MyAppCompat` class. On the `onCreate` method you call the super first which adds the FAB. But then you call `setContentView` and set a new layout which replaces the FAB previously added. Possible fix is to add the layout first and then the FAB. But you have to call the original onCreate from AppCompatActivity first. So create a new method called `addFAB` in your `MyAppCompat` class and put the code for the FAB here.
Then in your Home class do something like

```
 public class Home extends MyAppCompact 
{
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home); 
        addFAB();
     }
 }
```

Comment: You will not believe it, but I already guessed it myself).

Only it is bad that at such approach, it is necessary to add to each Activity also these methods ...

Comment: Did you try using addContentView for the layout in the main activity also? Then the FAB won't be replaced. But i'm not sure about the Z order.

Comment: Yes, I tried. It all depends on the number of code in the first Activity